# How to code for a probability map in opencv?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, probability

Hope I am posting in correct forum.

Just want to sound out my ideas and approach to solve problem. Would welcome any pointers, help (if given code would definitely be ideal :) )

**Problem:**
I want to code for the probability distribution (in a 400 x 400 map) in order to find the spatial location (x,y) of another line (let us call it fL) based upon the probability, in the probability map.

I have gotten a nearly horizontal line cue (let call it lC) from prior processing to calculate the probability to determine fL. fL is estimated to lie at D distance away from this horizontal line cue. My task is to calculate this probability map

**Approach:**

1) I would take the probability map distribution as Gaussian and to be

> P(fL | point ) = exp( ( x-D )^2 /sigma^2 )

which is giving probability of the line fL given the point in line cue lC is at D distance away, pending on sigma (which defines how fast the probability decrease)

2) I would use a LineIterator to find every single pixel that lie on the line cue lC (given that I know the start and end point of line). Let say I have gotten n pixel in this line

3) For every single pixel in the 400 x 400 image, I would calculate the probability using 1) as described above for all n points that I have gotten for the line. I would sum up each line point contribution

4) After finishing all the pixel calculation in the 400x400 image, I would then normalize the probability based the largest pixel probability value. This part I am not unsure that I should normalize by the sum of all pixel probability or by using the step above.

5) After this I would multiply this probability map with other probability map. So I would get

> P(fL | Cuefromthisline, Cuefromsomeother....) = P( fL | Cuefromthisline)P( fL | Cuefromsomeother).....

And I would set pixel with near 0 probability to be 0.001

6) That outlines my approach

**Question**

1) Is this workable? Or if there is any better method to doing this? ie getting the probability map

2) How do I normalize the map. by normalizing with the sum of all pixel probability or by normalizing with the max value

Thanks in advance for reading out this long post

Comment: If you're asking if this is mathematically the right approach, maybe math.stackexchange.com would be a better address. For the implementation of the outlined algorithm you need to provide your code, expected and actual results and formulate a specific question (you posed at least 3 very broad and off-topic questions so far: "is this workable" we don't know, that depends on your application, "is there a better method" in what way? performance? correctness? robustness to precision errors? etc...)

Comment: so sorry, I will pose this elsewhere. can this question be closed?